# Uploading Images through another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the Paperclip Gem.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
  has_many :reviews
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :photo
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end
```

This works `images/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @image do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :photos_attributes do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image, :multiple => false %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Image controller:

```
def create
  @image = @business.images.new(image_params)
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = "Image uploaded!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I want to be able to upload images also with reviews. I'm thinking something like this:

```
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.fields_for :photos_attributes do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image, :multiple => false %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit Review with Image'%>
<% end %>
```

How would my review controller look since image is from the image model and the rest is from the review model?

Comment: Have you tried with nested attributes: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I assume your review class `has_one :image` or something similar?

Comment: What is the relation between Image and Review models?

Comment: @doz87 I've updated the code. Business owners can already upload images of their business. The new feature is to allow users to submit reviews with images for a business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would lay it out is like this -

**Models**

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
  has_many :reviews

end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :business
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

end
```

I've added in `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` because you need to let your Review controller save the image while its saving itself. I'm not sure how you have got the Business controller set up but I would advise doing it the same way, its clearer and makes more sense.

**Review View - Form View**

```
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_area :content %>
     <%= f.fields_for :images do |photo| %>
         <%= photo.file_field :photo, :multiple => false %>
     <% end %>
     <%= f.submit 'Submit Review with Image'%>
 <% end %>
```

I've changed the form slightly to enable the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` to work better.

Finally the Review Controller

**Review Controller**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController


  def new

  @review = Review.new
  @review.images.build

  end

  def create

  @business = Business.find(id_of_business_your_reviewing)
  @review = @business.reviews.build(review_params)

  if @review.save

      puts "Saved"
      redirect_to "path"
  else

      puts "Something failed"
      render 'new'

  end

  end

private

    def review_params

    params.require(:review).permit(:content, :images_attributes => [:id, :photo])

    end

end
```

This will allow you to create a new review and add a photo to it through Image. There is no need to go to the Image Controller as Review has access to it and can accept its attributes.

I would suggest implementing something similar to the Business model when your creating/editing Businesses. I would have those actions performed with the Business Controller and use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` to allow it to accept its attributes.

Hope this helps to answer your question. Let me know if I haven't explained something properly.

Answer (score 1):

By your design you will not be able to know which images belongs to which review instead all images will be under the parent business of that review.

A good design is to use polymorphic association for the Image model.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :images, as: :parent
 has_many :reviews
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
 has_attached_file :photo
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :images, as: :parent
 belongs_to :business
end
```

and use one of the two possible solution i suggest in case 1.**Note that no.2 is better**.

Check [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) if you do not know how to build polymorphic associations.

---

**Case 1 For models that have a relation Like Business Model ::**

you can either :

1 - Add a new action to the **business_controller** to add the image like your code using the form you already wrote in the question for image but with the route to the action.
The form should have header like

```
form_for @image, :url => whatever_path_to_the_action
```

**or**

2 - Use **accept_nested_attributes** in the model and use new and edit action that you already have in the **business_controller** without any more code and the images will be saved with the business whether it is new or if you just edit it to add new images and in views use **fields_for**.

**see this link if you are not familiar with** [accept_nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and also this [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) for constructing your forms.

- **same goes to review as well if you followed the suggested design.**

---

**For Models that has no relation like Review Model in your design::**

you can add action to **reviews_controller** add_image.

```
def add_image
  @image = @review.business.images.new(image_params)
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = "Image uploaded!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'YOUR FORM'
  end
end

<%= form_for @image, url: path_to_the_action_add_image do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit Review'%>
<% end %>
```

**This is not a good design if you are interested to know which image belongs to which review to display with that review**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add image with review. You should have some relation between them. I have added `has_one` relation. Which is ideally fits in your condition. You can add `has_many` also. Your model should look like this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :images
 has_many :reviews
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :business
 belongs_to :review
 has_attached_file :photo
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :image
 belongs_to :business
end
```

Your form should look like :

```
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= fields_for :image do |i| %>
    <%= i.file_field :photo %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit Review'%>
<% end %>
```

If you are using rails 4. Changes require in your controller:

```
def create
  @review = Review.create(review_params) #This will create photo as well
  redirect_to xyz_path
end

private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:content, images_attributes: [:id, :photo, :_destroy])
  end
```

You need to add database changes as well. So make changes accordingly. (Add `review_id` in your photo model)

I have used simpler way. You can use polymorphic association as well for image and other models.

Comment: Thanks Nitin. This does not seem to be working. I don't understand the line: `tasks_attributes: [:id, :photo, :_destroy]` At what point am I actually saving the image?

Comment: Sorry I have misspelled it. It should be `images_attributes` I have updated my answer.